# Custom implementation of intermediate repository in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I am using Spring Data in my project and I have plenty of repositories. Now I wanted to add a method to some of the repositories, but not all of them, so I have created an interface `LoggingRepositoryCustom`, that (simplified) looks like this:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface LoggingRepositoryCustom<T extends IEntity, ID extends Serializable> {
     <S extends T> S save(S entity, AppUser author);
}
```

As I need to have a custom implementation of this, I have created also  `LoggingRepositoryImpl`, that implements this interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public class LoggingRepositoryImpl<T extends IEntity, ID extends Serializable> implements LoggingRepository {
      @Override
      public <S extends T> S save(S entity, AppUser author) {
           //impl
      }
}
```

Lastly, I have some repositories, that should have the functionity above, e.g. `AppUserRepo`:

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<AppUser, Long>, LoggingRepositoryCustom<AppUser, Long> {
      //methods of this repo
}
```

However, when I try to deploy this application, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property save found for type AppUser!
```

It seems that the custom implementation is not reflected and Spring Data tries to create a magical method from the name convention, thus looking for property "save" of `AppUser`, which does not exist. Is there a way to implement an interface, that is further extended by other interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add the same issue in one of my project ... and i did as follow to get it working :

1 - create your "parent" interfaces and implementations :

Repository :

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface LoggingRepository<T extends IEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, Long>, LoggingRepositoryCustom<T, ID> {
}
```

Repository custom

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface LoggingRepositoryCustom<T extends IEntity, ID extends Serializable> {
     <S extends T> S save(S entity, AppUser author);
}
```

Implementation of the repository custom :

```
public class LoggingRepositoryImpl<T extends IEntity, ID extends Serializable> implements LoggingRepositoryCustom<T, ID> {
      @Override
      public <S extends T> S save(S entity, AppUser author) {
           //impl
      }
}
```

2 - Create your specific interfaces and implementations :

repository :

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepo extends LoggingRepository<AppUser, Long>, AppUserRepoCustom {
}
```

repository custom :

```
public interface AppUserRepoCustom<AppUser, Long> {
}
```

repository implementation :

```
public class AppUserRepoImpl extends LoggingRepositoryImpl<AppUser, Long> implements AppUserRepoCustom {
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Well, this works when I implement AppUserRepo and the methods inherited from LoggingRepo, but I do not want to create an implementation of every single repository that would extend LoggingRepo, because the implementation is the same for all the classes...

Comment: You need to create an "empty" custom implementation of every single repo which `extends LoggingRepositoryImpl` (common logic being implemented in that parent custom repo) in order to tell spring data that it should generate those custom code ...

Comment: Well, yes, this is more or less a solution to my problem. I will implement this, however, if it was possible to avoid creating an empty implementation of all repositories, that would be much nicer :) Thank you for your reply!