# Spring Boot QueryDsl java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, querydsl

```
    //Page<Board> result = (Page<Board>) repo.findAll();
    Page<Board> result = repo.findAll(builder, pageable);
    System.out.println("넘어오긴했음");
    System.out.println("PAGE SIZE : "+result.getSize());
    System.out.println("TOTAL PAGES : " + result.getTotalPages());
    System.out.println("TOTAL COUNT : "+ result.getTotalElements());
    System.out.println("NEXT : "+result.nextPageable());
    
    //List<Board> list =new ArrayList<Board>(result.getContent());

    //list.forEach(b -> System.out.println(b));
```

it returns java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

how can i get Page by  use  findall  method?

most said edit here

```
List<Board> list = result.getContent();
```

to

```
List<Board> list =new ArrayList<Board>(result.getContent());
```

but my problem is occured

```
Page<Board> result = repo.findAll(builder, pageable);
```

here is trace

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.put(Collections.java:1459)
at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visitConstant(JPQLSerializer.java:327)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:221)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:36)
at com.querydsl.core.types.ConstantImpl.accept(ConstantImpl.java:140)
at 
com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:122)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:301)
at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visitOperation(JPQLSerializer.java:422)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:262)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:36)
at com.querydsl.core.types.OperationImpl.accept(OperationImpl.java:83)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:122)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:298)
```

Comment: What is the exact stack trace? What exactly throws the `UnsupportedOperationException`?

Comment: i add my exceiption trace. thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PagingAndSortingRepository `findAll` method allow only `Pageable` parameter

```
public interface PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {
  Iterable<T> findAll(Sort var1);

  Page<T> findAll(Pageable var1);
}
```

so if you want findAll method return `Page` through `querydsl` with builder
then extend CustomRepository like this [custom-implementation-of-intermediate-repository-in-spring-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712466/custom-implementation-of-intermediate-repository-in-spring-data)

Answer (score 0):

I think `findAll` can accept a `Pageable` parameter,

```java
Page<Board> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

This is not related to `QueryDSL`.

Check my [samples of Spring Data JPA/QueryDSL](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-sandbox/blob/master/data-jpa/src/main/java/com/hantsylabs/example/spring/jpa/ConferenceRepository.java)(You should update to the latest Spring yourself).